# Leer texto, convertir a string y hacer un split en visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Hola estoy iniciandome en visual basic y quería hacer lo siguiente leer un fichero y poder hacer un split sabiendo su delimitador. Pero en mi caso la ruta va a ser la del mismo archivo ejecutandose entonces yo hago lo siguiente:

```
Dim drop() As String = Split(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.ExecutablePath), "[SPLITTER]")
```

Lo que estaba intentando es hacer ambas cosas por separado o al menos buscar otra manera de poder leer mi fichero y usar un split solo se me ocurre está querría si algun experto sabe alguna otra manera para poder hacerlo.

Al mismo tiempo lo que hago es cifrar:

```
Function unsecure(ByVal data As Byte()) As Byte()
        Using sa As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
            sa.IV = New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
            sa.Key = New Byte() {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
            Return sa.CreateDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length)
        End Using
    End Function
Dim drop() As String = Split(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.ExecutablePath), "[SPLITTER]")

            Dim File1 As Byte() = unsecure(Convert.FromBase64String(drop(1)))
            Dim File2 As Byte() = unsecure(Convert.FromBase64String(drop(3)))
```

Pero no entiendo exactamente que es lo que hace? me encripta y desencripta la cadena?. Y otra pregunta es si podría prescindir de él del siguiente modo:

```
Dim File1 As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(drop(1))
Dim File2 As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(drop(3))
```

Y si pregunto es porque no entiendo este metodo -> FromBase64String. Creo que es para obtener la string decodificada?
Soy muy nuevo en visual basic así que cualquier crítica es bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a las instrucciones relacionadas con Base64, el problema es que cuando se transmite o graba una serie de bytes en formato de texto, los bytes con valor mayor que 64 no están definidos dentro del estándar ASCII.

El formato de Base64, codifica estos bytes utilizando dos caracteres en lugar de uno.

Por eso necesitas las funciones fromBase64String, para convertir la cadena codificada en Base64 en un array de bytes.

El formato de Base64 es muy común en la transmisión de datos entre sistemas como el formato MIME.